# change the color of expand-icon in vuetify expansion-panel-header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify expansion panel and just want to change the color of the expand panel in header to white. Unfortunately, the api does not have any options for color of expand icon and only color for the background of header. [Link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel-header/#props)

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header expand-icon="mdi-menu-down" color="#4527A0">
      <div><b> I am Header </b></div>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content color="#F1F8E9">
      <div><b> I am Content </b></div>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think there is any api just for color, but you can pass a custom icon and change the color from there. The example below will have the same shape as the default, but with a custom color.

```
<v-expansion-panel-header>
   <template v-slot:actions>
            <v-icon color="primary">
              $expand
            </v-icon>
          </template>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```